# Amazon S3 Low Level API uploading Large files

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 Low Level API for uploading Large Video File, I am following [This link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html)

When I am upoading the file, its giving me exception

```
The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

I have checked Inner Exception and its saying this

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

at this line

```
 CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse =
                    s3Client.CompleteMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
```

and this is how I am making my S3Client

```
 IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accesskey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

I also tried changing bucketname like bucketname/filename.mp4,but its giving exception

```
The specified upload id is not valid
```

I also tried some other file(doc and pdf) it is also giving XML exception.

Is there any good alternate approach for uploading Large Video files(Around 200-500MB)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to send archives to S3 (around 100-300MB). My code looked like this:

```
AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey);
s3Client.PutObject(new PutObjectRequest {BucketName = destinationBucketName, FilePath = myFilePath, Key = Path.GetFileName(myFilePath)});
```

That's it basically. I had retry-policy and exception handling around that, but this is the core. So just simple PutObject function without any multipart uploads works find for such file-sizes.

Comment: Can I send Large file with it?Not Archive just single file

Comment: Yes, I see no difference between archives and other file types. The only difference comparing to your multipart-upload may be that if something happens (connection lost) during upload - you have to start from scratch. But that's a rare case and was completely fine for us (retry policy handled this).

Answer (score 2):

I've found a similar problem during a MultiPart upload using the sample code in the doc. I've found that the ETag list is mandatory for the CompleteMultipartUpload part - which is not in the documentation sample.

This link has a better explanation of the multi-part upload process: [s3 multipart upload](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/)